# Update progress not working

Tags: asp.net

Update progress not working.The code is given below,When i am clicking on any button in the grid(paging,filtering etc) the progress is working.But when i am clicking on the image button the progress not working.

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="upnlStockList"
        DisplayAfter="0" DynamicLayout="true">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <div class="PopupPanel">
                <table style="vertical-align: middle; width: 100%; height: 900px">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="middle" align="center">
                            <img id="Img1" src="~/Images/loading.gif" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlStockList" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Always">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <grid></grid>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="imgPDF" />
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="imgExcel" />
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="imgCSV" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    protected void imgExcel_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
     {
            (initializing the report and assigning parameter).
            ReportProcessor reportProcessor = new ReportProcessor();
            RenderingResult result = reportProcessor.RenderReport(PDF, rptStockList, null);
            string fileName = result.DocumentName + ".pdf";
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = result.MimeType;
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
            Response.Expires = -1;
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("{0};FileName=\"{1}\"", "attachment", fileName));
            Response.BinaryWrite(result.DocumentBytes);
            Response.End();
     }
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

script manager in master page
By clicking the image button i am downloading the report as pdf.

Comment: Do you have scriptmanager somewhere in your code?

Comment: thank u for the reply.....yes...in master page and progress working with grid actions(paging,filtering)

Comment: Debug your button click event. check it's firing or not.

Comment: yes.. its firing and pdf download also happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>
```

The AsyncPostBackTrigger Specifies a control and event that will cause a partial page update for the UpdatePanel that contains this trigger reference.

```
<asp:PostBackTrigger>
```

The PostBackTrigger Specifies a control and event that will cause a full page update (a full page refresh). This tag can be used to force a full refresh when a control would otherwise trigger partial rendering.

So try to use like this.

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="imgPDF" />
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="imgExcel" />  
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="imgCSV" />
```

Hope this may helpful...

Comment: thank you for reply..i tried with above code"<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="imgPDF" />
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="imgExcel" />  
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="imgCSV" />".Now update progress working.But i need to download report as pdf,this is not happening.

Comment: You mean to add this code"<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="imgPDF" />".Then download is happening but progress not showing

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is

```
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="imgPDF" />
```

try AsyncPostbackTriggers instead.

Check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398821.aspx)

like I said, it only works with asynchronous postback.

> The UpdateProgress control renders a  element that is displayed or hidden depending on whether an associated UpdatePanel control has caused an asynchronous postback. For initial page rendering and for synchronous postbacks, the UpdateProgress control is not displayed.

For the file download problem you encountered. You should read this [AJAX, file downloads, and IFRAMEs](http://encosia.com/ajax-file-downloads-and-iframes/)

Comment: When i am adding "AsyncPostbackTriggers" the pdf download not happening

Comment: Do you tie the event with it as well ? And where is your button ? Is it in updatepanel ?

Comment: now i tried with  "<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="imgPDF" EventName="Click" />".Now progress working but download not happeing

Comment: good ! I just fixed your question and bring you another one lol.

Comment: What browser do you use ? FF ? try IE instead.

Comment: ok, use firebug to see what you get from Response. BTW, I think you should start a new question, since this is different from the current one. The current one is fixed basically. lol

Comment: I think I know what is the problem. Download is caused by the header you add. I think it won't work with partial render, since partial render doesn't go through header. I think you might try to wrap it in an iframe.